# Extract data from tables via Forms Recognizer V3 nuget in C# with a custom model

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-form-recognizer

Create a custom model in form recognizer in which you make 2 types of tags, one is of type "field" and the other is the "table" which I was accommodating cell by cell. Once my model was trained and tested, I proceeded to create an API in .net 6 that will perform the analysis and extraction of the information and have the possibility of creating a web application.

I have only one problem, in the following code it is returning me a Json that at first glance I thought everything was correct, since it even created a client where it showed all the information obtained by key/value/confidence.

My Code:

```
            AzureKeyCredential azureKey = new(_formRecognizerKey);
            DocumentAnalysisClient analysisClient = new(new Uri(_formRecognizerEndPoint), azureKey);
            AnalyzeDocumentOperation analyzeDocumentOperation = await analysisClient.AnalyzeDocumentFromUriAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, _formRecognizerCustomModelId, new Uri(urlblob));
            AnalyzeResult result = analyzeDocumentOperation.Value;
            foreach (AnalyzedDocument document in result.Documents)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DocumentField> fieldKvp in document.Fields)
                {
                    string fielName = fieldKvp.Key;
                    DocumentField field = fieldKvp.Value;¿
                    response.DocumentsFields.Add(new DocumentFieldResult { Key = fielName, Values = field.Content, Confidence = confidence });
                }
            }
```

In the keys that are tables they are returning a null value, I debugged the code in the lines:

```
AnalyzeResult result = analyzeDocumentOperation.Value;
            foreach (AnalyzedDocument document in result.Documents)
                   foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DocumentField> fieldKvp in document.Fields)
                {
```

The result objt is returning everything perfectly, all the information I need is there, but since I comment out the ones that are labeled as table, the value comes out as null.
I tried to test code that was in the documentation to go around but I see that it is not what I need since I am not interested in doing an OCR analysis, I am interested
That the analysis be based on my model.

Now... with all the comments, should the tables be treated differently? In the debug I see that the FieldType in those that are fields come in string and in the case of those that were labeled as tables they come as FieldType:List.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax to extract the content of dynamic tables defined in your custom model in Azure Form Recognizer v3.0

```
              if (document.Fields.TryGetValue("<dynamicTableFieldName>", out DocumentField itemsField))
                    {
                        if (itemsField.FieldType == DocumentFieldType.List)
                        {
                            foreach (DocumentField itemField in itemsField.Value.AsList())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Item:");

                                if (itemField.FieldType == DocumentFieldType.Dictionary)
                                {
                                    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, DocumentField> itemFields = itemField.Value.AsDictionary();

                                    if (itemFields.TryGetValue("<dynamicTableColumnName>", out DocumentField itemDescriptionField))
                                    {
                                        if (itemDescriptionField.FieldType == DocumentFieldType.String)
                                        {
                                            string itemDescription = itemDescriptionField.Value.AsString();

                                            Console.WriteLine($"  Description: '{itemDescription}', with confidence {itemDescriptionField.Confidence}");
                                        }
                                    }

                                   
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I got this code from this link [[here]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/how-to-guides/use-sdk-rest-api?view=form-recog-3.0.0&tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-csharp)